# What is the formal definition for "view" in this context?

Tags: pytorch, tensor, definition

Consider the following paragraph from the sub-section named **[The essence of tensors](https://pytorch.org/assets/deep-learning/Deep-Learning-with-PyTorch.pdf#page=73)** from the section named **Tensors: Multidimensional arrays** of the chapter named **It starts with a tensor** from the book titled **Deep Learning with PyTorch** by *Eli Stevens et al.*

> Python lists or tuples of numbers are collections of Python objects
> that are individually allocated in memory,  as shown on the left
> in figure  3.3.  PyTorch tensors or  NumPy arrays, on the other
> hand, **are views** over (typically) contiguous memory blocks
> containing *unboxed* C numeric types rather than Python objects. Each
> element is a 32-bit (4-byte) float in this case, as we can see on the
> right side of figure 3.3. This means storing a 1D tensor of 1,000,000
> float numbers will require exactly 4,000,000 contiguous bytes, plus a
> small overhead for the metadata (such as dimensions and numeric type).

And the figure they are referring to is shown below, taken from the book

[image]

The above paragraph is saying that tensors are views over contiguous memory blocks. What exactly is meant by a view in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "view" is how you interpret this data, or more precisely, the shape of the tensor. For example, given a memory block with 40 contiguous bytes (10 contiguous floats), you can either *view* it as a 2x5 tensor, or a 5x2 tensor.

In pytorch, the API to change the view of a tensor is `view()`. Some examples:

```
Python 3.8.10 (default, Sep 28 2021, 16:10:42) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import torch
>>> x = torch.randn(10, dtype=torch.float32)
>>> x.shape
torch.Size([10])
>>>
>>> x = x.view(2, 5)
>>> x.shape
torch.Size([2, 5])
>>>
>>> x = x.view(5, 2)
>>> x.shape
torch.Size([5, 2])
```

Of course, some views are forbidden for 10 floats:

```
>>> x = x.view(3, 3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: shape '[3, 3]' is invalid for input of size 10
```

`view` does not change the data in the underlying memory. It merely changes how you "view" the tensor.